# how to Pass table name to PL SQL cursor dynamically?

Tags: plsql, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have written one SQL Procedure where I have written one cursor and every time i have to pass table name to cursor query dynamically .

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE Add_DEN as 


v_TableName VARCHAR2(4000) := 'BO_USER_DATA';

cursor c_DEN is select * from BO_USER_DATA; // Want to pass dynamically ,now hardcoded
r_DEN c_DEN%ROWTYPE;

fetch c_DEN into r_DEN; 
v_Name := r_DEN."Name";
```

Can i write something like this

```
cursor c_DEN is "select * from " || v_TableName;
```

Any Help ?

Comment: Are you sure you've tagged this question correctly? Because none of `create or replace`, `varchar2`, `:=` nor `%ROWTYPE` work in SQL Server.

Comment: The code example is not T-SQL

Comment: Do you really need a cursor? There are a few times when a cursor should be used but they are very frequently used when there is no need for one. Almost anytime you are doing DML you don't need a cursor.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It is PL SQL . because we are executing this using SQL developer on Oracle.

Comment: Go read about EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and/or DBMS_SQL package.

Answer (score 2):

here an example:

```
declare
  TYPE curtype IS REF CURSOR;
  l_cursor curtype;
  l_param  number;
  l_key number;
  l_value number;
  l_sql varchar2(200);
begin
  /* build your sql... */
  l_sql   := 'with data as (select 1 key, 100 value from dual union select 2, 200 from dual union select 3, 300 from dual union select 3, 301 from dual)' ||
         ' select key, value from data where key = :1';
  l_param := 3;

  open l_cursor for l_sql
    using l_param;

  loop
    fetch l_cursor
      into l_key, l_value;
    exit when l_cursor%notfound;

    dbms_output.put_line(l_key||' = '||l_value);
  end loop;
  close l_cursor;
end;
```

Result:

3 = 300

3 = 301

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is yes, you can and Given your example I would recommend you to use execute immediate to execute an arbitrary SQL string and bind the variables.
I would nevertheless reconsider if you really needed to dynamically set the table as this is not very often really needed.

Example:

```
DECLARE
   sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(200);
   emp_id      NUMBER(4) := 7566;
   emp_rec     emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM emp WHERE empno = :id';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO emp_rec USING emp_id;
END;
```